# How can I get latest block?

Tags: go-ethereum

I installed and run `geth` on local node in my Ubuntu 16.04.
After start the `geth` in testnet, I got highest block by `eth.sync`.
This highest block was similar with the latest block of `ropsten.etherscan.io`.
But `eth.sync` is returning same result with first one.
So I can't get the latest block from syncing.
Is this right way?
How can I get highest block?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal type `geth attach` then type `eth.blockNumber` if you are not getting the latest block number then blockchain is not fully synced, Also you should use ssd otherwise it will take forever to sync with hdd...

After blockchain is fully synced you will be able to get latest block number.